# Openal Soft + hrtf

Tags: android, openal, openal-soft

I want to use Openal Soft for my Android game to support realistic 3D audio. I would like to use the hrtf functionality of Openal Soft. How do I enable it? Is there some config file I have to modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I receiver the following message from the Openal-soft team:

Currently (version 1.16), you need to modify ~/.alsoftrc (or /etc/openal/alsoft.conf for it to be global for all users), and add:

[general]
hrtf = true